# WooCommerce image Thumbnails SAME Size

Tags: wordpress, function, content-management-system, woocommerce

Is possibile set same size of every image in woocommerce product catalog?

Example:

I want thumbnails image 200 x 200 px.

But if i upload image 100x100?

I need a force zoom on this image to adapt for my woocommerce thumbnail 200 x 200 px.

Is possibile?

I see several option on woocommerce menu, but they have not been useful.

Comment: There is no way to upscale images for thumbnails in WordPress, by default. You'll need to add in a custom image processor that can handle that kind of action...or just upload larger images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using WooCommerce Settings.

WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Display -> Product Images

Set the catalog images to 200px 200px and check hard crop option.

After saving these settings make sure you [regenerate thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to update the existing images according to the new settings.

You can also refer to [this](https://youtu.be/4sUpt3M1DO0) video for some of the steps.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858692/woocommerce-image-thumbnails-same-size#answer-50234799) by Warface for the up-to-date method.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer was true until now. The actual WooCommerce version now put the display option in Appearance -> Customize

Then select WooCommerce -> Product Image to set the custom size or ratio.

Comment: However, to prevent thumbnails from being cropped, you can use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-image-resize/